# How to change apparmor logging file?

Tags: apparmor, logs

Apparmor logging to syslog by default. How to change apparmor config to logging to /var/log/apparmor.log for example?

Answer (score 2):

logfiles for apparmor can be read from `/etc/apparmor/logprof.conf`
You can use `aa-logprof -f /var/log/apparmor.log` command to let apparmor read logs from it.

Now to send log entries to a different file (e.g. apparmor.log):

```
touch /var/log/apparmor.log
sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log/apparmor.log
sudo chmod 640 /var/log/apparmor.log
sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.d/10-apparmor.conf
```

Add those 2 lines to the file:

```
:msg,contains,"apparmor" /var/log/apparmor.log
& stop
```

then
`sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`

To verify:

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
sudo tail /var/log/apparmor.log
```

Now you should no longer see any apparmor entries in syslog:
`sudo tail /var/log/syslog`

Comment: This is not working as expected. Logs like restarting apparmor go to /var/log/apparmor.log but more important logs like denied entries go to audit.log.